# Looping problem in AS3 when using ROLL_OVER

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So basically I am trying to make a banner that adds and removes a movie clip on ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT with a button. I have the movie clip created, and the button, and it works fine if I only use ROLL_OVER. As soon as I add an eventListener for ROLL_OUT, it loops the functions like crazy and the movie clip keeps flashing on and off. I know I am missing something simple, but I can't get my mind around what. Here's the code:

```
       var MySmiles:smilesEvery=new smilesEvery();

       buttonSmiles_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, smiles, false, 0, true);
       function smiles(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
         this.addChild(MySmiles);
       };
       buttonSmiles_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, smilesOUT, false, 0, true);
       function smilesOUT(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
        this.removeChild(MySmiles);
       };
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

removing listeners might help:

var MySmiles:smilesEvery=new smilesEvery();

```
   buttonSmiles_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, smiles, false, 0, true);

   buttonSmiles_btn.mouseChildren = false //to be shure, that one of the childs interfire with mouse events

   function smiles(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
     this.addChild(MySmiles);
     buttonSmiles_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, smilesOUT, false, 0, true);
   };
   function smilesOUT(myevent:MouseEvent):void {
    buttonSmiles_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, smilesOUT, false,0,true);
    this.removeChild(MySmiles);
   };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am now getting a 1119 error: access of possibly undefined property mouseChildren through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton. Any thoughts?

Comment: Aha i see, u are using button. I thought you are using movieclip. Error comes from line 2 (buttonSmiles_btn.mouseChildren = false) remove that and you should get rid of error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: on roll over you show a clip, that overlaps your button.
Hence, you get an immediate roll out on the button. 
Which in turn causes your button to recieve roll over again.
That causes a recursive stack overflow. :)

If the above holds true, just disable mouse on MySmiles. 
Both mouseChidren and mouseEnabled.